# How to fusion two indexes in a pandas DataFrame to create only one in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I have a DataFrame with two indexes (called Year and Month) and one column (PL):

```
GB.head()
```

```
Year  Month     PL
1997  1        707.272727
      2        -94.545455
      3         22.727273
      4       -244.545455
      5        467.272727
```

I need to fusion the values of the two indexes in one new column.
The result should be this:

```
New Index       PL
1997-1        707.272727
1997-2        -94.545455
1997-3         22.727273
1997-4         -244.545455
1997-5         467.272727
```

I guess that the solution could be extract the values of each index, after that fusion them in a new column and establish that column as the new index. But I am lost with that.

Could someone help me with this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `f-string`s:

```
df.index = [f'{a}-{b}' for a, b in df.index]
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael. Do you mean this way?: GB.index = [f'{Year}-{Month}' for Year, Month in GB.index]: I tried but I get this error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @Martingale - What is `print (df.index[:3].tolist())` ?

Comment: Ok I reset the Kernel in the Jupyter Notebook and it worked perfectly. Thank you jezrael! :)